# Javascript: return true if ALL strings inside an array are present in another string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, comparison

I have to check if a string inside a variable has **all** the strings inside an **array** on it. Very simple I thing, but I cant get it to work! I have tried a lot of things but are to complex and not really working. I'm looking to some suggestion.

Something like:

```
var myArray = ["cat","dog","bird"];
var myString = "There is a cat looking the bird and a dog looking the cat";
var myString2 = "There is a cat and a dog looking one each other";
```

myArray and **myString** must be true and **true** and myArray and **myString2** must result **false**

I was working with something like this:

```
var selector = "dir.class#id";
var code = '<div id="id" class="class"></div>';
var tokens = selector.split(/[\.,#]+/);

for (var i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var counter = [];
    if (code.indexOf(tokens[0]) > -1 ) {
        counter.concat(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Show what did not work. We are not going to code your "homework" for you. It is just a simple for loop and reg exp or indexOf.

Comment: Should "dog" match "dogs" or not?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I know that is a simple for loop, but I was really blocked. I'll post what I did after checking the answers!

Comment: @RobG it should not match `dogs` but should match something like `idog`. This is because some words have a preceding character like `id` or `class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like bellow

```
var arePresentInText = function (text,words) {
    return words.every(function(word){
        return text.indexOf(word) > -1;
    });
}

console.log(arePresentInText(myString,myArray)); //prints true
console.log(arePresentInText(myString2,myArray)); //prints false
```

Comment: Really nice and ultra fast response! Thanks! What is the compatibility of `.every` I have heard that in some browsers you need a Polyfill to make it work. What is your experience?

Comment: And this solution is wrong based on your comments in the question above.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 var myArray = ["cat","dog","bird", "cat"];
 var myString = "There is a cat looking the bird and a dog looking the cat";
 var myString2 = "There is a cat and a dog looking one each other";

 function checkValue(arr, str){
    var cnt = 0;
    for(i in arr){
        var val = arr[i];
        if(str.indexOf(val) > -1) cnt++;
    }

    return (arr.length == cnt) ? true : false;
 }

 console.log(checkValue(myArray, myString));
```

Comment: I mark the solution that uses .every because is shorter but I really like this one! I thing that can be used with older browser, that is right?

Comment: Ya, indexOf has issues with older version of Internet Explorer. But these days people started forgetting about older version of IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkContainStr(arr, str){
for(i in arr){
    if(str.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)
     return false;
}
 return true;
}
```

Comment: This one is nice but It's going to check one by one and not if **all** the elements of the array are present in the array. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sergio it will not check all the element in case of not match first string or any middel elements  in array .if not match then for loop won't execute next step, because there this return statement  in the for loop .and it matching ur requirements also

Answer (score 0):

Try this function out:

```
function arrayElementsInString(ary, str){
  for(var i=0,l=ary.length; i<l; i++){
    if(str.indexOf(ary[i]) === -1){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What advantage is gained by *RegExp* over *indexOf*? And *match* is probably much slower than *test*.

Comment: I love this regex @DanD. I still have problems working my way around using regex and this is a nice example!

Comment: The regex I stated was incorrect. it would match `cat cat cat`. I was attempting to avoid a factorial sized regexp but it seems that one can't.

Comment: @DanD. So I suppose that I should tested it before praise it. Anyway is constructive for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match strings at the end of words but not necessarily at the start, you'll need to use either a regular expression or other processing.

Checking with *indexOf* matches the character sequence anywhere in the word, not at the end. Consider the following which matches the strings either at the end or as the whole word:

```js
    var myArray = ["cat","dog","bird"];
    var myString = "There is a cat looking the bird and a dog looking the cat";
    var myString2 = "There is a cat and a dog looking one each other";
    var myString3 = "There is a classcat and a iddog looking at bird";
    var myString4 = "There is a catclass and a dog looking at bird";

    document.write(myArray.every(function(word) {
      return (new RegExp('\\w*' + word + '\\b').test(myString));
    }) + '<br>');
    document.write(myArray.every(function(word) {
      return (new RegExp('\\w*' + word + '\\b').test(myString2));
    }) + '<br>');
    document.write(myArray.every(function(word) {
      return (new RegExp('\\w*' + word + '\\b').test(myString3));
    }) + '<br>');
    document.write(myArray.every(function(word) {
      return (new RegExp('\\w*' + word + '\\b').test(myString4));
    }));
```